# How fast must I stir the glass of water to get it boiling?

Tags: temperature, kinetic-theory

I have a glass of water at room temperature and I decided to add more and more kinetic energy by stirring it with a plastic spoon so that it starts boiling... can this be done? if so how fast must I stir? (both manually and mechanically.)

Comment: Have you seen https://what-if.xkcd.com/71/

Comment: @onurcanbektas thanks for the link but where do all the kinetic energy goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this scenario examined in [what-if xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/71/)

> When you stir tea, you're adding kinetic energy to it, and that energy
>   goes somewhere. Since the tea doesn't do anything dramatic like rise
>   into the air or emit light, the energy must be turning to heat.
>   [...]The reason you don't notice the heat is that you're not adding
>   very much of it. It takes a huge amount of energy to heat water; by
>   volume, it has a greater heat capacity than any other common
>   substance.

In other words, the energy does not go anywhere, it is just a small energy that you are putting into the water that it is negligible.

**Edit:**

> Even if you could churn the spoon hard enough—tens of thousands of
>   stirs per second—fluid dynamics would get in the way. At those high
>   speeds, the tea would cavitate; a vacuum would form along the path of
>   the spoon and stirring would become ineffective. [...] And if you stir hard enough that your tea cavitates, its surface area
>   will increase very rapidly, and it will cool to room temperature in
>   seconds: **No matter how hard you stir your tea, it's not going to get 
>   any warmer.**

Comment: so how fast do I stir for it to translate into "huge amount of energy"?

Comment: @user6760 see my edit please.

Comment: Experiment trumps theory. It is possible and cavitation does not stop it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjcOobt9Ef8

Comment: @The_Sympathizer You are ignoring the heat that is the water absorbs from the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a very naive approach to answer this question.

Energy of a rotating body, in this case, a cylindrical column of water, can be taken as the energy of a rotating solid cylinder in the roughest approximation.

Rotational kinetic energy of such a cylinder is: $\frac{1}{4}mr^2 \omega^2$.
If this energy is to be used to increase the temperature of the water, then for a mass $m$ of water with specific heat capacity of $c$, undergoing a temperature change of $\Delta T$, 
$$\frac{1}{4}mr^2 \omega^2 =mc\Delta T$$
This leads to 
$$\omega = \sqrt{ \frac{ 4c\Delta T}{r^2}}$$
If we try to use some sensible values in this equation, say, 
 c = 4200 J/kg$^\circ$C, $\Delta T$ = 80 $^\circ$C, and $r$=10cm (0.1 m), then we get a value of 8198 radian/sec for $\omega$, or roughly 1845 revolutions per second, or 110700 revolutions per minute.

Comment: I don’t see how this is relevant; fast-moving objects are not hotter. Maybe you have some process in mind in which you decelerate this rotating cylinder to turn the kinetic energy into thermal energy. If so, please add this reasoning and consider how it affects the heat transfer aspects of the question.

Comment: What you say, is right. I do not know of any process that translates and objects kinetic energy into its thermal energy. All I have done here, is under the assumption that there exists ways by which one is able to do so, this would be the frequency at which the object must be rotated.

Comment: BTW, since it is assumed that all the rotational energy is used to heat the liquid, the liquid will stop rotating and will only heat up once the rotational KE is converted to thermal energy.